# How to select a combobox value in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am trying to simply select an item in the dropdown list after it has been loaded into a store.  This does not work:

```
Ext.getCmp('ddlModel').setValue(aircraftStore.getAt(0).data.ModelTypeCode);
```

This throws an exception:

```
Ext.getCmp('ddlModel').selectByValue(aircraftStore.getAt(0).data.ModelTypeCode);
```

Here is the exception:
'this.view' is null or not an object

Anyone know how to do this in ExtJs?

Comment: as docs suggests use setValue. "The store must be loaded and the list expanded for this function to work, otherwise use setValue". it works for me as expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created a function to set the value of the combo box in ExtJs:

```
function ComboSetter(comboBox, value) {
    var store = comboBox.store;
    var valueField = comboBox.valueField;
    var displayField = comboBox.displayField;

    var recordNumber = store.findExact(valueField, value, 0);

    if (recordNumber == -1)
        return -1;

    var displayValue = store.getAt(recordNumber).data[displayField];
    comboBox.setValue(value);
    comboBox.setRawValue(displayValue);
    comboBox.selectedIndex = recordNumber;
    return recordNumber;
}
```

Comment: I have spent 6 hours to know how to display the correct string and found it in ```comboBox.setRawValue(displayValue);```

Answer (score 2):

`Ext.getCmp('ddlModel').select(aircraftStore.getAt(0));`

Comment: There must be a bug in ExtJs 3.4 because selectByValue and select both throw an exception even when the dropdown is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you may want to set the combobox to a certain index. In ExtJs 4.2 you can do this like so:

```
function setIndex(combobox, value)
{
    combobox.setValue(combobox.store.data.items[value].data.field1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I needed to get the id of the combobox, then compare in an if, and thus able to pass a second window, use this method and it worked.

```
var ValorSeleccionado = Ext.getCmp('cmb_tipoderol_usr').getValue(); // 'cmb_tipoderol_usr' is the id of the combobox.
```

then compare to the action

```
if (ValorSeleccionado == 1 ) { Do Action }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to configure your combobox with this property:

```
autoSelect: true
```

> true to select the first result gathered by the data store (defaults
> to true). A false value would require a manual selection from the
> dropdown list to set the components value unless the value of
> (typeAheadDelay) were true